# Confirming Google Analytics Install in Flash Environment using AS3 Mode

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-analytics, tracking

Just created a new GA account and initialized my tracker in AS3. How can I confirm that it is installed and working correctly? In GA web view it shows **"Tracking Not Installed"** but when I use the "visualDebug" parameter (set to true) in Flash, it appears to be sending OK via `trackEvent`. Would it not show up as installed since it's not on the website yet (just testing in IDE)?

```
var visualDebug:Boolean = true;
var config:Configuration = null;
var debug:DebugConfiguration = null;

tracker = new GATracker(this, _trackerId, "AS3", visualDebug, config, debug);

// ...

/** Handles analytics tracking. */
private function onTrackEvent(event:GameShellEvent):void
{
    track(_trackingCategory, event.action);
}

/** Track an event in google analytics. */
private function track(category:String, action:String):void
{
    trace("[GA] tracking event", category, action, "with id", _trackerId);
    tracker.trackEvent(category, action);
}
```

**Edit**

FYI, I'm using the AS3 library in "AS3" mode which sends the requests through a [GIF request](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/analytics/core/GIFRequest.as). This is *not* using the ga.js library so there's nothing to install on a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, guess I should have RTFM more thoroughly:

> Note: Currently, Flash tracking is
>   available for any Flash content
>   embedded in a web page. Tracking of
>   data sent from Adobe Air, Shockwave,
>   or via the Flash IDE (e.g. using Test
>   Movie) is not supported at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen this particular method of embedding Google Analytics code. However, I believe this is because you are running the content locally -- and for security reasons, remote communication is not permitted when running locally.

Comment: I was hesitant to make the above comment... but how can the Google Analytics tracking code be accessed without ExternalInterface calls? I must be missing something.

Comment: It makes URLRequests to a .gif file which handles the track. From the docs: "AS3 mode is completely independent from the ga.js tracking code and contains all the Analytics tracking functionality."

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/analytics/core/GIFRequest.as